# How to show a dialog with FutureBuilder when press a button?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, future, builder

I upload an image FirebaseStorage with FutureBuilder and when I press upload button I want to show a waiting dialog. Image upload successfully on FireStorage but nothing shows up. Whats wrong my codes? I think FutureBuilder return Widget and press button void. Maybe it is the problem. Or I am calling FutureBuilder wrong way. Do you have any tips or suggestions for my wrong code?

Here is my code;

```
    Widget buildBody(BuildContext context) {
        return new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Column(
            children: [
              new SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: new RaisedButton(
                  child: new Text('Upload'),
                  onPressed:  () {
                    futureBuilder();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }

     Future mediaUpload() async {
        final fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + '.jpg';
        final StorageReference storage = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
        final StorageUploadTask task = storage.putFile(_image);
        return task.future;
      }

      Widget futureBuilder() {
        return new FutureBuilder(
          future: mediaUpload(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                print('ConnectionState.none');
                return new Text('Press button to start.');
              case ConnectionState.active:
                print('ConnectionState.active');
                return new Text('');
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                waitingDialog(context);
                return waitingDialog(context);
              case ConnectionState.done:
                print('ConnectionState.done');
                if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                print(snapshot.data.downloadUrl);
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('home');
                return new Text('Result: ${snapshot.data.downloadUrl}');
            }
          },
        );
      }

      waitingDialog(BuildContext context) {
        return showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return new Center(
              child: new SizedBox(
                width: 40.0,
                height: 40.0,
                child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                  value: null,
                  strokeWidth: 2.0,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure why `FutureBuilder` is not working. But I have a guess. In the above example, `FutureBuilder` is **not attached** to the widgetTree(screen). Not attached means **value returned** from `FutureBuilder` is not displayed in screen. In this case, `Text` is returned based on `snapshot.connectionState` which is not attached to screen.

**Work around:** *(I tested and it worked, can you please verify)*

```
futureBuilder(BuildContext context) {
  mediaUpload().then((task) {          // fire the upload
    Navigator.of(context).maybePop();  // remove the dialog on success upload
  });                                  // we can use task(which returned from
                                       // mediaUpload()) to get the values like downloadUrl.
  waitingDialog(context);             // show the spinner dialog
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dinesh it works like a charm. But how can use with FutureBuilder? I don't get it.

Comment: I will try to find why `FutureBuilder` is not working in this case. I looked into `FutureBuilder` but didn't get anything. I think my guess is correct :-P. If I find something, i will let you know. Please do the same

Comment: I am trying to figure out also. If I get anything I will let you know too.

Comment: any solution for calling alert dialog from future builder?